# Java set value of double without rounding

Tags: java

*First of all please note that I couldn't find the answer on google so that's why this question is very simple*

So I was trying to make a java program that involved looking at the colour of pixels in an image, and plugging that into a neural network.

I made a method to try and turn the hex into input for the neural network. (that means values from 0 - 1)

```
public double[] toHex(int a)
{
    char[] hex = Integer.toHexString(a).toCharArray();
    double[] out = new double[6];
    for(int i = 2; i < hex.length; i++)
        switch(hex[i - 2])
        {
            case('0'):
                out[i - 2] = 0D;
            case('1'):
                out[i - 2] = 0.066D;
            case('2'):
                out[i - 2] = 0.133D;
            case('3'):
                out[i - 2] = 0.2D;
            case('4'):
                out[i - 2] = 0.266;
            case('5'):
                out[i - 2] = 0.333D;
            case('6'):
                out[i - 2] = 0.4D;
            case('7'):
                out[i - 2] = 0.466D;
            case('8'):
                out[i - 2] = 0.533D;
            case('9'):
                out[i - 2] = 0.6D;
            case('a'):
                out[i - 2] = 0.666D;
            case('b'):
                out[i - 2] = 0.733D;
            case('c'):
                out[i - 2] = 0.8D;
            case('d'):
                out[i - 2] = 0.866D;
            case('e'):
                out[i - 2] = 0.933D;
            case('f'):
                out[i - 2] = 1.0D;
        }
    return out;
}
```

But for some reason, doing this always results in either a 1.0 or a 0.0 when I'm looking at the generated code. Can someone please explain what's going on?

*EDIT* I'm sorry. I'm quite stupid. I was looking at a particular section that only displayed 0's and f's. But I did forget the break though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `break`s at the end of each case. It should look more like

```
switch(hex[i - 2])
{
    case('0'):
        out[i - 2] = 0D;
        break;
    case('1'):
        out[i - 2] = 0.066D;
        break;
    // ...
}
```

Without these, the program falls through from one `case` to the next, each one overwriting the result from the last. Since the last case has `out[i - 2] = 1.0D`, this is the result that you will always see from the `switch`.

Comment: Thanks, I did forget these, but it's something else. I put that in, but it still only ever outputs either '1.0' or '0.0'. After all, it wouldn't make sense if it said hex[i] - 2 == '0' and then hex[i] - 2 == '1' as well.